# Properly update TweenMax rotation on element

Tags: gsap

I'm currently attempting to animate an object 180 degrees every X seconds by incrementing the amount of rotation using TweenMax. Specifically the 2D transforms within the [CSSPlugin](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/).

**Current Issue**

At the moment every time a new "animation" is triggered, the element resets its rotation to zero degrees and then transitions to 180 degrees.

**Intended Results**

What I'd like to do is have it to where an additional 180 degrees is added to the current total rotation every time. Eg: 180, 360, 540, etc.

**Current Snippet & Example**

Here is the bulk of my TweenMax code:

```
TweenMax.to(el, 1, {
  rotation: '+=180',
  repeat: -1,
  repeatDelay: 1,
});
```

The full example can be viewed [here](https://jsbin.com/pexodar/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: I think you may be looking for `.invalidate()`. See [this](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/8888-rotation-values-and-timelinemax-infinite-repeat/#entry35442).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @ajames ?

Answer (score 1):

GSAP will apply the "short" way how to reach the end rotation in your animation. You should instead tell the library how you want the rotation to be applied using `_cw` or another options.

Live example:

https://jsbin.com/ridoqa/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#box');

TweenMax.from(el, 1, {
  rotation: '+=360_cw',
  repeat: -1,
  repeatDelay: 1,
});
```

More infos:
https://greensock.com/forums/topic/7997-rotate-the-shortest-way/

Comment: Changing the rotation to 180 causes the same problem as well.